# Hierarchical state machines: on_enter on nested machine calls parent methods

Tags: python, transition, fsm

I am using pytransitions/transitions module and trying to build some hierarchical state machines.

In the snippet below, I am triggering a transition from one nested state to another.

The problem is that if I attach on_enter callback to the destination nested state, the library is searching for this callback in the parent machine.

```
from transitions.extensions import HierarchicalMachine as Machine
from transitions.extensions.nesting import NestedState as State

class Nested(Machine):
    def print_msg(self):
        print("Nested")
    def __init__(self):
        self.states = ['n1', {'name':'n2', 'on_enter':'print_msg'}]
        Machine.__init__(self, states=self.states, initial='n1')
        self.add_transition(trigger='goto_n2',
                            source='*',
                            dest='n2')

class Top(Machine):
    def print_msg(self):
        print("Top")
    def __init__(self):
        self.nested = Nested()

        self.states = [  't1',
                        {'name': 't2',
                        'children': self.nested}]
        Machine.__init__(self, states=self.states, initial='t1')
        self.add_transition(trigger='goto_t2',
                            source='*',
                            dest='t2_n1')



top_machine = Top()
top_machine.goto_t2()
top_machine.goto_n2()
```

The output of the script is "Top"

If I remove print_msg() from the Top class, then I am getting AttributeError.

While in theory I can have the callbacks in the top machine, I would definitely prefer to keep my states and callbacks together in the well defined boundaries of the nested machine.

Any idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

From the related Github [issue](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions/issues/248):

String callbacks are always looked up in the model which in your case is the Top machine.
If you do not pass a specific model instance to `Machine` it will serve as a model itself.
For more complex scenarios I'd suggest do split the machine (transitions and related rules)
and model (actual state based behaviour).

When you pass a `Machine` instance to another HSM, the rules and transitions will be copied and not just reused. That's why `Nested` will use itself as a model but the nested version will use `Top` instead. Having just copies of `Nested`'s assets has two advantages: first, it does not intervene with the original Nested instance and second, it allows to reuse many functionality provided by core which otherwise had to be rewritten and as a result cause higher code complexity.

The 'easiest' way would be to pass callbacks by reference rather than by name. Instead of 'on_enter':'print_msg' use 'on_enter':self.print_msg. This way the callback reference is already resolved which prevents transitions to look it up in the model (**Note: This has been bugged until transitions 0.6.1**).

```
from transitions.extensions import HierarchicalMachine as Machine


class Nested(Machine):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        states = ['1', {'name': '2', 'on_enter': self.print_msg}]
        transitions = [['finish', '*', '2']]
        super(Nested, self).__init__(states=states, transitions=transitions,
                                     initial='1')

    def print_msg(self):
        print("Nested")
        self.parent.print_top()


class Top(Machine):

    def print_msg(self):
        print("Top")

    def __init__(self):
        self.nested = Nested(self)

        states = ['A', {'name': 'B', 'children': self.nested}]
        transitions = [dict(trigger='print_top', source='*',
                            dest='=', after=self.print_msg),
                       dict(trigger='to_nested', source='*', 
                            dest='B_1')]

        super(Top, self).__init__(states=states, transitions=transitions,
                                  initial='A')

top_machine = Top()
top_machine.to_nested()
top_machine.finish()
```

As mentioned above, I'd also suggest splitting machine and model. This way you can use MixIns to decorate your main model and keep the code less cluttered. This way you can also use every tool OOP has to offer to alter the state machine's behaviour.